# Qual é a diferença entre um oxímoro e uma antítese?

Tags: figura-de-estilo

Após ler os artigos da Wikipédia sobre [Oxímoro (Paradoxismo)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oximoro) e [Antítese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%ADtese), fiquei na dúvida quanto à distinção entre os dois.

Segundo a Wikipédia, um Oxímoro:

> [Exprime] conceitos contrários (...).

E uma Antítese:

> (...) Consiste na exposição de ideias opostas (...).

Como é que os posso diferenciar mais facilmente? Há alguma diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As descrições dadas de *oxímoro* e *antítese* estão corretas, embora facilmente confundidas.

Temos uma antítese quando, numa expressão ou sequência de frases, são expostas ideias opostas que se contrastam mutuamente. Um extremo não anula o outro. Exemplos:

> Por **um lado**, gosto de gelado. Por **outro**, tenho muita sensibilidade dentária.
>
> Ela vestiu-se toda de branco, de **cima** a **baixo**.
>
> Este novo modelo atinge o **máximo** de velocidade com o **mínimo** de esforço.

Num *oxímoro*, os conceitos fazem uma colisão irracional. Esta figura de estilo costuma ser usada para representar incertezas, ideias/sensações inexplicáveis ou para criar sarcasmo. O famoso poema de Camões recorre imensamente a esta.

> Amor é **fogo que arde** *sem se ver*,
>
> É ferida que **dói**, e *não se sente*
>
> É um **contentamento** *descontente*,

Comment: "cima" e "baixo" são conceitos opostos, que não se contrapõem. Torna-se uma antítese por definição.

Comment: Ahh! Então é essa a diferença! Para ser uma antítese, só têm de estar na mesma frase, mas para ser um pardoxismo, tem de formar um ... paradoxo. Certo?

Comment: Também podem estar em frases adjacentes, mas o essencial é esse.

Comment: @E_net4 adorei os teus exemplos :)